# there is a problem with gridlayout in android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-gridlayout

When I try to add grid-layout it takes the full screen. But I want it to set below these elements but I can't. what to do now?
I can't find any solution on youtube or any other platform so I have to post here.
Actually, I'm learning android app development for the first time. I copy-paste the same code from the instructor but nothing happens. maybe he is using an older version of android studio and I'm using the latest version.

Anyway please someone help me to solve this problem. And if possible please explain the problem. I'll really thankful to you guys.

[image: look the screenshot]

and also this text also appears. How can I remove this text?

[image: also this]

> here is my XML code I paste here..please find my mistake and solve this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#02F837"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="#00F10A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F4DC01"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="30s"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F4DC01"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.953"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#58F15E"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="31 + 12"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03" />

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="202dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="197dp">

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Please share your layout xml. regarding the text, that just appears in the Android Studio's layout editor tool, wont be there in your app so not to worry.

Comment: ok I'll add my code to this post

Comment: We would be needing your complete layout xml. Also, I can see you have set the width/height to match_parent so it is supposed to take up the whole space inside its parent.
Please provide more details since your query doesn't provide sufficient information.

Comment: I have pasted full XML code.Please check this now

Comment: If you want your GridLayout to be below the TextViews  then you need to set the top of GridLayout to the bottom of one of your TextViews as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this the what you want to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/constraint1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/startButton"
        android:layout_width="203dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#02F837"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:text="Go!"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:backgroundTint="#00F10A"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="OnClick"
        android:layout_marginTop="200dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F4DC01"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="30s"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.046"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointsTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#F4DC01"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="0/0"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.953"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.029" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sumTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#58F15E"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="31 + 12"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.03" />


 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/constraint2"
    android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/constraint1">

    <androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridLayout"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="202dp">

        <!--
             now you can add whatever button you want to add here
             -->

    </androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, bro. But a little mistake is there. Please ignore the "GO" button because it is a clickable button if the user presses this button then it will disappear so I need grid layout below the numbers textView

Comment: Ok but other than that everything worked right?